# Could not load file or assembly EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've deployed an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and the home page loads fine, but when I try to access any other page (which all try to connect to a SQL database) I get this error:

> **Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.** The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've checked the Web.config file and it has the following relevant entries:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
...
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
```

I've read everything I could find via Google but nothing as helped so far. I know that somehow the version of EF I built the application with is different than the version that's on the deployment machine but I could use some direction in how to correct this difference.

Comment: Can you not push the EF library to the server?  Do you have EF in the GAC on the server?

Comment: Do you have EntityFramework dll in your bin directory ?

Comment: You seem to be using EF5 on .NET Framework 4 (hence the version 4.4.0.0 in your config file) but the exception you get is talking about EF 4.1 (the version is 4.1.0.0). It seems like some assemblies you are using still try to use 4.1 while the other EF5 (4.4.0.0). Make sure you reference the same assembly everywhere. Also the entry in the config file is just to point the .NET Framework to a Type that knows how to read the config section so it is not enough to update this to make the app work against EF5

Comment: @Justin Sorry, I don't know what GAC is.

Comment: @Shyju Yes, I have EntityFramework.dll in the bin folder.

Comment: @Pawel Does this mean I should be looking at other referenced dll's besides EF as the culprits?

Comment: Did you use Nuget to add EF to the project? Else you maybe should try redoing that.The Nuget package will modify the references and the entries in the config file.

Comment: @Splendor: yes, check your project if you don't have references to other versions of EntityFramework.dll. Check if you don't have some stale EntityFramework.dll files. You should not have EntityFramework.dll in GAC it is meant to be bin deployable.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks! You were right. The data model domain project in the same solution was referencing an older version of EF. I updated that reference, rebuilt, and it resolved the issue. If you want to add your comment as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Splendor: I turned my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You seem to be using EF5 on .NET Framework 4 (hence the version 4.4.0.0 in your config file) but the exception you get is talking about EF 4.1 (the version is 4.1.0.0). It seems like some assemblies you are using still try to use 4.1 while the other EF5 (4.4.0.0). Make sure you reference the same assembly everywhere. So, you need to update all the references to use EF5 and rebuild the project. 
Btw. the entry in the config file is just to point the .NET Framework to a Type that knows how to read the config section so it is not enough to update this to make the app work against EF5

Answer (score 6):

you can try the following:

in the solution explorer go to the reference node and locate `EntityFramework` reference node and then in its properties set to `False` the property `Specific Version`

then remove the version identifier from your `web.config`, replace:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

with simply:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false" />
```

in this way the error related to mismatching versions should b solved.

still like other said in the comments, it is good if you get all your references from NuGet and check-in everything in your source control system.

this approach has worked for me many times for many assembles and does not require any more changes in the web.config when you upgrade to a newer version of the EF later on.

Comment: Specific Version was already set to false and unfortunately, changing the suggested line in the Web.config didn't change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Before going through the fun of updating all the references, try restarting Visual Studio.  This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while trying to debug a project locally on IIS Express.

I manually unloaded the site by opening the the IIS Express options and selecting `Stop Site`. Then I was able to proceed normally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a little bit different. The DLLs were completly missing in the GlobalAssemblyCache and were not deployed by VS. I had to deploy the EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll to GAC, so a GAC Deployment with the following Powershell script worked:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")            
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish            
$publish.GacInstall("C:\Path_To_DLL\EntityFramework.dll")
$publish.GacInstall("C:\Path_To_DLL\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your project name conflicts with a nuget package that you referenced. I wasted about 3 hrs before I realized what is going on.
So, avoid from entering same name like reference name

Answer (score 0):

For every reference and error encountered, find the corresponding DLL file, and unblock it by right-clicking on it