# Unable to use Entity Framework in WCF Service on SharePoint 2013 server

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, wcf, sharepoint

We are trying to create a WCF web service which will connect to SQL Server using Entity Framework. The WCF Service will be deployed on SharePoint 2013 mapped to `ISAPI` folder on SharePoint hive.

We are able to deploy the solution in SharePoint 2013 server, but whenever we call the web service it returns error as below

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=XXXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.\u000d\u000a File name: 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX'\u000d\u000a
>   at ()\u000d\u000a   at \u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a"

In `App.Config` file we have below code.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  ...

  </configSections>
<configuration>
```

We created a simple console application on same SharePoint 2013 server and the code ran successfully.

What are we missing here?

Comment: how are you deploying the WCF ?
have you installed EF to the project thats getting hosted ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan: We deploy it using Visual Studio to SharePoint server. The EF DLLs are present in the project itself.

Comment: this is a common error due to EF DLLs missing there are other solutions available here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905818/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the entity framework DLL needed to be present in the GAC. Despite being present in the SharePoint solution, it was not referring to it.

We added entity framework DLLs to GAC and it has now started working.